# google-speech API transcription response gets repeated multiple times

Tags: python, google-cloud-speech

I am using latest python library of google-cloud-speech (0.35.0) and I am getting results as follows, words from the first transcript result is repeated in second transcription result and so on till the end. This was not the case in the prior release (0.34.0)

Refer source code.

**Source code:**

```
config = speech.types.RecognitionConfig(
            encoding=enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.FLAC,
            sample_rate_hertz=48000,
            language_code='en-US',
            alternative_language_codes={'en-IN'},
            # max_alternatives=10,
            profanity_filter=True,
            enable_word_time_offsets=True,
            enable_word_confidence=True,
            enable_automatic_punctuation=True,
            enable_speaker_diarization=True,
            diarization_speaker_count=5,
            #model="video",
            use_enhanced=True)
```

**Result:**

```
results {
    alternatives {
        transcript: "start"
        confidence: 0.632519185543
        words {
            start_time {}
            end_time {
                seconds: 5
                nanos: 900000000
            }
            word: "start"
            confidence: 0.655210196972
            speaker_tag: 1
        }
    }
}

.....
.....
.....

results {
    alternatives {
        transcript: "end"
        confidence: 0.632519185543
        words {
            start_time {}
            end_time {
                seconds: 5
                nanos: 900000000
            }
            word: "start"
            confidence: 0.655210196972
            speaker_tag: 1
        }
        words {
            start_time {
                seconds: 129
                nanos: 300000000
            }
            end_time {
                seconds: 130
                nanos: 400000000
            }
            word: "end"
            confidence: 0.624447464943
            speaker_tag: 1
        }

    }
}
```

**Questions:**

1. Why I am getting multiple results in the response?
2. What is the reason to repeat words in all result sets? Previously each result set would contain only the words spoken during that time frame.

Comment: Can you include the code part that prints the response result?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Google notes something similar to this in their documentation

> Note: When this is true, we send all the words from the beginning of
>   the audio for the top alternative in every consecutive responses. This
>   is done in order to improve our speaker tags as our models learn to
>   identify the speakers in the conversation over time.

https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.speech.v1p1beta1#google.cloud.speech.v1p1beta1.RecognitionConfig